# Office365 - Exchange Mailflow Rules for Signature

Tags: exchange, office365

im using Office365 / Exchange and I have setup a nice HTML template to attach dynamic
E-Mail signatures using the Mailflow-Rule: "attach disclaimer".

I have used the attribute %%PhoneNumber%% its always empty even though contact-information its perfectly filled in UserAccount and Exchange.

Whatever I do it stays empty.

Then I started to use %%CustomAttribute1%% - and I entered "333333" like two hours ago.
The string in the E-Mail stayed Empty.

Then after 30 more minutes desperately messing arround, all of a sudden it worked to display 333333.

Now two hours ago I replaced this test-string with the real phone number, disabled/enabled the rule, updated the rule. Updated the user-profile, both in Office365 Admincenter and in Exchange...

Its still displaying "33333". Its frustrating because I never know or can test if I udpated/used the correct field nor if it worked at all.

Is Exchange using a very aggressive Cache or is it just very slow?
The documentation on the placeholders is very bad aswell. There is a list of variables without explaining what field the variable exactly belongs to.

Some work, some do not.

If the variable cannot be resolved it throws an error upon saving (atleast) but if saves and stays empty this is not helpful either.

Comment: TBH, I'd open a support case in your tenant. It's free and they'll help you get it resolved.

Comment: Thanks I'd do that. Because its frustrating that its soo hard to impossible to actively debug except for applying, waiting and testing and you dont know if you hit correct or you gotta change that information in Exchange, in Teams, in AD. Who knows what field is being read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to docs.microsoft.com there you have an overview of all the values you can use.

Maybe activation of the rule with PowerShell it goes quicker. Yes the EAC can be slow.

```
    %%City%%
%%Company%%
%%CountryOrRegion%%
%%Department%%
%%DisplayName%%
%%Fax%%
%%FirstName%%
%%HomePhone%%
%%Initials%%
%%LastName%%
%%Manager%%
%%MobilePhone%%
%%Notes%%
%%Office%%
%%Pager%%
%%Phone%%
%%PostalCode%%
%%PostOfficeBox%%
%%StateOrProvince%%
%%StreetAddress%%
%%Title%%
%%UserPrincipalName%%
%%WindowsEmailAddress%%
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/security-and-compliance/mail-flow-rules/disclaimers-signatures-footers-or-headers#use-exchange-online-powershell-to-add-a-disclaimer-or-other-email-header-or-footer

Comment: Thanks, Ive been there.
It just lists the available variables.

Is phone number from AD? addtional contact info? Group?
Who knows~ I was not able to make MobilePhone work.

I've set-up all things in the user-profile and it still remained empty after 30 minutes.

The only good thing is, that if you set a variable that could not be resolved you get an error. Everything from THIS list works, but if it still remains empty its still very hard to debug or make work. The documentation here is very bad due to lack of info what actual fields

Comment: ...the variabled are mapped to.

Comment: The variables use the attributes from azure ad